# Is Base64 dependent to the original file that it has been generated from?

Tags: image, base64

In order to convert Base64 file that is created from a format like png , to another format like Bitmap, do we have to convert it first to original format and then to Bitmap or we can directly convert it to desired format and its not dependent to its original format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to think about base64, is that any file *usually* looks like it's encoded in 8 bits. There's nuance here. Base64 is a way to reencode bytes into a stream of bytes that only uses 6 bits.

By reencoding a file that uses all 8 bits to only use 6 bits, this allows things to be sent in contexts that don't allow the entire 8 bits to be used. One example is a URL, another could be a text file.

So when a PNG is encoded as Base64, it's still a PNG. The underlying information is all the same, it's just encoded slightly different.

If you base64 encode something, and then base64 decode it again it's the *exact same bytes*.

Comment: Bottom line, the OP has to decode from base64 prior to  decoding png format and encoding into bmp

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to the original format, and then to the new target format. However, you could do this in one go by creating a steam that decodes base64 and feed that stream to the image decoding. You then re-encode to the new image format and save to file. No intermediate file is needed.